# prometheus scraped time series data not showing at higher time ranges

Tags: prometheus

In the following image, you can see I have two occurrences:

[image]

However, at 1d, the occurrences display strangely and can't be seen.

[image]

Does this have to do with resolution? That's a difference I see, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It looks as though you had a single measurement at 14:23:06. I suspect when you rescale the graph over 24 hours, Prometheus may pick sample times that don't include that specific, one-off measurement, for example it chose 14:23:00 and 14:23:15 and so you see the flat graph.

Comment: For infrequent but significant measurements such as this, you can use PromQL's [`<aggregate>_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) functions e.g. `max_over_time(anka_instance_state_count{State="Terminated"}[15m])` where `15m` defines the window of time. In this case, you would (!) then see an extended bump (15-minutes wide) of such non-zero events.

Comment: I would also add that this is not a grafana, but prometheus' own Web ui. If memory  serves, grafana will automatically aggregate data if resolution used by panel bigger than resolution of metric. If this is not the case, you can do it manually with query like `sum_over_time(anka_instance_state_count{State="Terminated"}[$__interval])`